# Examples of the local Langlands correspondence

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory

I'm trying to compile some examples of the local Langlands correspondence, with the aim of motivating the statement and also just giving some concrete traction on how it works. I would especially like to see examples that were historically used by Langlands to discover the correspondence, but all nice examples are welcome.

So far I have the tori, the Weil(-Deligne) representations of real and complex groups, and the unramified representations.